# ¿Cómo puedo validar que un dato no sea nulo?

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

  while (reader.Read()){
          Piece p = new Piece();
          p.Released_Date = (DateTime) reader["Released_Date"];


            }
   }
```

¿Cómo puedo validar el dato "Released_Date"?
Cuando ejecuté el código, me mando un error diciendo que uno de los datos es nulo.

Comment: ¿Has probado `reader["Released_Date"] == null`?

Comment: Si pongo 
if(p.Order_Date == null)
{
 } ¿Cómo puedo continuar? En caso de que el dato de la base de datos sea nulo.

Answer (score 5):

La comparación correcta, tratándose de un resultado de base de datos, sería así:

```
System.DBNull.Value.Equals(tu_objeto)
```

Para hacerlo más *genérico* puedes pensar en una función:

```
bool IsDbNull(object resultado)
{
    if (resultado == null) return true;
    return System.DBNull.Value.Equals(resultado);
}
```

Aplicándolo a tu código, yo lo haría de esta manera:

```
p.Released_Date = IsDbNull(reader["Released_Date"]) ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)reader["Released_Date"];
```

Answer (score 2):

El objeto `String` tiene un método que comprueba si el parámetro tiene valor asignado.

```
while (reader.Read()){
    Piece p = new Piece();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Released_Date"])){
        //Released_Date no es null
        p.Released_Date = (DateTime) reader["Released_Date"];
    }
}
```

Comment: `reader["Released_Date"]` no es un string, es un object. Estas seguro de que este código funciona?

Comment: Si crees que lo que digo en mi comentario es incorrecto, podemos hablarlo, pero no considero que sea ofensivo. Mi intención solo era hacerte ver que el código de tu respuesta ni siquiera compilará (no se puede convertir de `object` a `string`)